# python converting .tif to .png without changing mode from cmyk to rgb

Tags: python, graphics, python-imaging-library

I want to convert .tif to .png. Simple solution I found was

```
import Image

im = Image.open('39.tif')
im.save('39.png')
```

This didn't work and gave me following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Marijus/Desktop/templates/rename.py", line 8, in <module>
    im.save('Foto.png')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1441, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py", line 506, in _save
    raise IOError, "cannot write mode %s as PNG" % mode
IOError: cannot write mode CMYK as PNG
```

After a little bit of googling I found out that if I wanted this to work, I had to change mode from CMYK to RGB

```
if im.mode == "CMYK":
    im = im.convert("RGB")
```

And it worked, however it changed colours. How can I convert from .tif to .png without changing mode from cmyk to rgb ?

Answer (score 0):

PNG-Files have only the modes Indexed, Gray, RGB and RGBA. That's the file format, so if you need CMYK use another file format, e.g. TIF.

Answer (score 0):

I use next code for work with tiff

```
    from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

    image = Image.open(content)

    for i, page in enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(image), 1):
        filename = os.path.splitext(file_info.filename)
        page_name = "{}_{}{}".format(filename[0], i, ".png")
        page_bytes_io = io.BytesIO()
        page = page.convert("RGB")
        page.save(page_bytes_io, "png")
        page_bytes_io.seek(0)
        yield page_name, page_bytes_io, page
```